# C# program where size of array index and elements are from user input and then search for a specific element

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a program where the size of array index and its elements are from user input.
And then the program will prompt the user to search for a specific element and will display where it is.

I've already come up with a code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

class Program
{

  public static void Main(String [] args)
  {
    int a;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter size of index:");
    a= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int [] index = new int [a];
    for (int i=0; i<index.Length;i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter number:");
      index[i]=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

  }
}
}
```

The problem with this is that I can't display the numbers entered and I don't have any idea how to search for an array element.
I'm thinking of using if statement.

Another thing, after entering the elements the program should display the numbers like Number 0 : 1

Is this correct: `Console.WriteLine("Number"+index[a]+":"+index[i]);`?

And where should I put the statement? after the for loop or within it?

Comment: +1 for knowing to label this as homework despite it being your first post. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the last line `Console.WriteLine(index[i]);`? It seems like you are using the loop variable outside the loop.

To display entered numbers (ie. if I understand well, the numbers in the array), you have just to walk through the array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < index.length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(index[i]);
}
```

Since you want display numbers only after every number is entered, you may put this code only after finishing the loop where the user is entering the numbers:

```
// The user is entering the numbers (code copied from your question).
for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
    index[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}

// Now display the numbers entered.
for (int i = 0; i < index.length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(index[i]);
}

// Finally, search for the element and display where it is.
int elementToSearchFor;
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out elementToSearchFor))
{
    // TODO: homework to do.
}
```

To search for a number, you can either walk through the array again and compare each element until finding a good one, or use Linq `TakeWhile()` method. (I suppose that your intent is not to use Linq, so I don't provide any further detail in this direction.)

Comment: for (int i=0; i<index.Length;i++)

    {

      Console.WriteLine("Enter number:");

      index[i]=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

      Console.WriteLine(index[i]); *

    }
That line surely displays the entered number but then I was prompted to enter a number again. How can I display the entered numbers after I completed entering all the numbers?

Comment: @unsub101: "How can I display the entered numbers after I completed entering all the numbers?" - see the sample code in my answer. It does exactly what you need.

Comment: That's odd, because when I tried running the program, the number i entered was displayed but then it prompts me again to enter another one.

Comment: Where are you putting the loop? Probably you have embedded loops, when two loops are expected to go one after another: the first to capture values, the second to display them.

Comment: Is that for loop inside the first loop? 
umm, like this?
  for (int i=0; i<index.Length;i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter number:");
      index[i]=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int j = 0; j < index.length; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(index[j]);
}
    }

Comment: Yes. I edited my answer to be more easy-to-understand. By the way, I recommend using `TryParse` instead of `Parse` when dealing with user input. I imagine you might not be familiar with `TryParse` and `out` parameters, so I included an example.

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track. Look carefully at how you stuffed values into the array, and you might find a clue about "how to search for an array element" with  specific value. This is a core introductory algorithm, so no shortcuts! You need to find the answer on your own :-).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Array.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof.aspx),

Answer (score 1):

```
        int a;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter size of Array:-");
        a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] array = new int[a];
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Elements of the Array:-");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe Elemets of the Array are:-");
        for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array[j]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to break down what you've done and what you still need to do

Create a program where:

1) size of its array elements comes from user input (check)
2) array elements come from user input (check)
**3) Prompt the user to search for a specific element (TODO)

4) Display where it is (TODO)**

From the code you've written so far I would think you have most of what you need to do #3 & #4

An if statement may come into play when finding the location of the element the user specifies.